# undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass for active record callback of existing field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a form with a checkbox of different styles. The form works fine, but I am getting an empty string saved in the array of style options.  I would like to remove it. So I created a before_save callback..

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","car_form"=>{"styles"=>["","Black"]}}
```

VIEW

```
<%= f.input :styles, as: :check_boxes, collection: FormCollection::Styles.all %>
```

MODEL

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :remove_empty_from_styles

  def remove_empty_from_styles
     styles = (styles - ['']) if styles_changed?
  end
end
```

However, I get:

> undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

However, if I comment out the call back everything works fine, the values get saved, like normal.

NOTES: `styles` is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `styles` on `self`:

```
def remove_empty_from_styles
  self.styles = styles - [''] if styles_changed?
end
```

`styles = styles - ['']` assigns the result of `styles - ['']` to a local variable called `styles`.

`self.styles = styles - ['']` invokes a `styles=` method on `self` passing `styles - ['']` as an argument.

Comment: did you intentionally make self.style = styles?

Comment: This is the correct solution, but it would be a better answer if it explained why the error was occurring in the absence of `self.`.

Answer (score 1):

You could change it in a number of ways:

1. Using `try`:

   ```
   self.styles = styles.try(:-, ['']) if styles_changed?
   ```
2. Another version using `try` but this has the benefit of being able to handle both empty strings *or* `nil` values:

   ```
   self.styles = styles.try(:reject, &:blank?) if styles_changed?
   ```

Note that in both examples, I've added `self`. `self` is typically implicit in Ruby, but when you're assigning an attribute, you'll have to specify `self` because otherwise there's no way to distinguish whether you're declaring a local variable or assigning a value to an attribute.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, but styles is not nil, so the issue is not so much the method to remove the blank items, but to figure out why its seeing styles as nil.

Comment: It's got to be. Put in a `puts styles.inspect` above where you're removing the empty strings so you can see exactly what the value of `styles` is at the time of execution.